# Left/Right percentages differences between browsers

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have a button at the bottom of a table, in the middle of the bottom of the table, centered. I did add `left:30%` and `right:30%` so the button locates at the middle, however, I noticed in Chrome this get rendered differently than Safari or Firefox, in Chrome, the percentages are not the same, thus the button ends up a little more to the left than right, and not centered/middled. Try it below. 
How can I get this to work the same in Chrome too? Why are the percentages rendered differently, what's the best technique to centre this element that needs to be in `absolute` positioning?

```css
.panel {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.table {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0px 20px 31px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09), 0px 8px 20px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height:350px;
  background:lightblue;
}

.table * {
  text-align: center;
}

.contact-button {
  bottom: -25px;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: 30%;
  right: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:absolute;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  outline: none;
  line-height: inherit;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;

}
```

```html
<div class="panel table">
  <a href="/contact"><button class="btn contact-button">CONTACT MORE INFO</button></a>
</div>
```

Comment: You're right, but tell me, why do you have a <button> in an <a>. That is totally counterproductive and counterintuitive, not to mention in error.

Comment: Oh thanks, this not answers the question. Does this affect the rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just move the `button` from the `div` and create something like this

```
<div class="panel table"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="btn contact-button">CONTACT MORE INFO</button>
</div>
```

This way you don't have to use `position:absolute;` you can just use

```
display:flex; 
justify-content:center;
```

If you want more support for older browser versions, please check this [article](https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/)

Check the example below

```css
.panel {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.table {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0px 20px 31px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09), 0px 8px 20px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 350px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.table * {
  text-align: center;
}

.contact-button {
  bottom: -25px;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: 30%;
  right: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  outline: none;
  line-height: inherit;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel table">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="btn contact-button">CONTACT MORE INFO</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Removing the position:absolute didn't work, so I still have the `position: absolute` and adding the wrapper as you suggested worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also it may help you without changing much things:

```
.contact-button {
 background: #f9f9f9;
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top:370px;

}
```

have a look on this bin: https://jsbin.com/gipibecedu/edit?html,css,output